# can both "LocalBean" and "Remote" be annotated on one bean?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I know it might sound elementary, but i'm wondering the following singleton bean:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
@LocalBean
public class MyServiceBean {
    public String sayHello() { return "Hello"; }
}
```

Now i think "remote" clients might need use this bean, so I want to add a Remote interface to this bean:

```
@Remote
public interface MyService {
    String sayHello();
}
```

Can I just make my bean implements the new remote interface?

If "MyServiceBean" implements the "MyService" remote interface, it will become a bean with a "remote-interface-view" ... but after I searched the web, you all said that a bean with annotation "LocalBean" is a "no-interface-view".

Is that able to work? or should I create a Local interface and remove the LocalBean annotation?

deeper thoughts... if "remote-view", "local-view" and "no-interface-view" are 3 types of view which can all exist in one bean....? can i have a bean that implements all of them?

```
@Local
@Remote
@LocalBean
public class Possible implements PosLoca, PosRemote {}
```

.... i'm really confused...

Comment: if a bean has both "local business" and "no-interface" business. which will be used with I use "@Inject" or "@EJB" in another bean in the same JVM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for a bean to expose multiple views (Remote business, Local business, no-interface).

The component can be the same - you just add another ways of accessing it.

Take a look at *EJB 3.1 FR* specification:

**4.4.2.2 Session bean exposing multiple client views (p. 86).**

```
package com.acme;

@Singleton(name="Shared")
@LocalBean
@Remote(com.acme.SharedRemote.class)
public class SharedBean { ... }
```

One note - I don't think the example you posted will work out-of-the-box. You're using `@Remote` and `@Local` without specifying the interface references. I don't think the container will now which interface is what. Either specify the `@Remote(clazz)` or annotate the interface itself as `@Remote`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. and one more question: if "MyService" is used in the same JVM, which "view" is injected to other beans? (since there are both "local business" and "no-interface" viewd at the same time in the case).

Comment: for the "@Remote(clazz)" part you mentioned, i have already annotated the interface with "@Remote", and make the bean class to implement it "... implements MyServiceRemote"... i knew the way you said, just not sure which way is better or equivalent?

Comment: 1. It depends what are you injecting? If you're injecting remote interface - it will be remote view, if local - it will be local, if the class itself - it will be the no-interface view. Mind that 'same JVM' is not enough. Two separate modules / application within the same app server / jvm cannot communicate with local business views (well, at least spec doesn't allow that but app server vendors often do). 2. It depends on what you want to have. If you want to have clean API without importing any EJB packages - annotate bean classes only. If not - you can choose - there is no golden rule here.